# Maximum Width of jQuery UI Tooltip widget

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I use jQuery UI's new [Tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) and having trouble with figuring out how to set a maximum width of the tooltip. I guess it should be done with *position*, but how?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Based on [Senni's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12956850/2430549), I added following to a separate CSS-file:

```
div.ui-tooltip {
    max-width: 400px;
}
```

A sidenote: Make sure your separate CSS follows *after* the ui-css, otherwise there will be no effect. Otherwise you also could use the `!important` - marker.

Comment: As an alternative, I prefer to add a more specific CSS rule so that it will take precedence over the jquery-ui.css rule, regardless of the order you link your stylesheets.  If you have an ID tag on your body, it's as simple as doing `#idOfBodyTag .ui-tooltip`

Comment: The !important is important.

Comment: `body div.ui-tooltip` seems to be enough regardless of load order.

Answer (score 35):

If you subscribe to Tooltip's open event, you can update the style in code:

```
$(".selector").tooltip({
    open: function (event, ui) {
        ui.tooltip.css("max-width", "400px");
    }
});
```

Comment: this works well. thanks. And this is better since you can make different tooltips  different sizes depending on your needs.

Comment: @sdjuan thanks for this.  I was trying to use "width", and it wasn't working even though "height" was.  "max-width" did the trick.

Comment: Do not use that! Jquery is calculating the width and hieght befor open is called. Therefore the size change will not be registered.

Answer (score 11):

in script:

```
$(elm).tooltip({tooltipClass: "my-tooltip-styling" });
```

in css:

```
.my-tooltip-styling {
      max-width: 600px;
}
```

Comment: This really seems like the best answer to me. You don't mess with jQuery UI's CSS, and you can set style for each tooltip individually. Thanks. This helped me realize I don't know what class/id to style since the tooltip doesn't actually live in my code, just jQuery UI.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of modifying or overriding the jQuery UI CSS classes directly, you can specify an additional CSS class using the **tooltipClass** parameter:

**Tooltip initialization**

```
  $(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip({
      items: "tr.dataRow",
      tooltipClass: "toolTipDetails",  //This param here is used to define the extra style class 
      content: function() {
        var element = $( this );

            var details = j$("#test").clone();
            return details.html();

      }
    });
  });
```

Then you would create that style class.  You will want to import this CSS file after the jQuery UI CSS file.

**Example CSS style**

This class here would make the modal 1200px in width by default and add a horizontal scroll if there is any more content beyond that.

```
<style> 
  .toolTipDetails {
    width:  1200px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    overflow:auto;
  } 

</style>
```

*Sidenote:  It is generally not recommended to use the `!important` tag but it could be used in this case to ensure that the intended `CSS` is rendered.*

Comment: This is no longer a valid solution .html() cannot be implemented as part of content parameter as HTML is no longer supported.

Comment: Well, the html() is used to populate the tooltip, not to style it, so the technique is still valid even if the scaffolding isn't

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by the [jQuery UI api](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#theming), the best you can do is override the classes **ui-tooltip** and **ui-tooltip-content** this way:

```
.ui-tooltip
{
    /* tooltip container box */
    max-width: your value !important;
}
.ui-tooltip-content
{
    /* tooltip content */
    max-width: your value !important;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can set the width like this in the js

```
$("#IDOfToolTip").attr("style", "max-width:30px");
```

or

```
$("#IDOfToolTip").css("max-width", "30px");
```

Comment: This somehow does not work, but based on this I added some CSS (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
  .ui-tooltip{
      max-width: 800px !important;
      width: auto !important;
      overflow:auto !important;
      }
  .ui-tooltip-content{
      background-color: #fdf8ef;
      }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
div.ui-tooltip{
width: 210px; //if fit-content not worked in specifics browsers
width: fit-content;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.