# Display Html Content in jQuery Tooltip for ASP.Net Repeater

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net repeater that displays a title and an image. The image appears based on some of the calculations I do in the repeater ItemDataBound event.

I tried to implement a mouse over using jquery tooltip . But I can only display the title in the tooltip. I would like to display other details bound to the repeater (errorcalls, totalcalls - I use these details to perform calculations in the code behind) too within the tool tip.
Can anyone help me with what I should do ? I have the code below .

Code for the repeater :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMonitorSummary" runat="server" 
OnItemDataBound="rptMonitorSummary_OnItemDataBound">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Panel ID="Pnl" runat="server">
         <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
            <h5 class="ui-widget-header" title="<%# Eval("Name").ToString()%> ">
               <%# Eval("Name").ToString().Length > 9 ? 
                 (Eval("Name") as string).Substring(0, 9) : Eval("Name")%>
            </h5>
            <div id="divHover">
               <asp:Image Width="80px" ID="btnPerformanceImage" 
                   runat="server" Height="45px"></asp:Image>
            </div>
         </li>
      </asp:Panel>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code Behind :

```
protected void rptMonitorSummary_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            int errorcalls = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "ErrorRatingCalls"));
            int totalcalls = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "TotalCalls"));

            float Percentage = 100 - ((((float)errorcalls / (float)totalcalls)) * 100);   

            if (Percentage == GetMaxMonitorThresholdValuebyLevelId(1))
            {
                    ((Image)e.Item.FindControl("btnPerformanceImage")).ImageUrl = "../Images/Level1.png";
            }

            else if (Percentage >= GetMinMonitorThresholdValuebyLevelId(2))
            {
                    ((Image)e.Item.FindControl("btnPerformanceImage")).ImageUrl = "../Images/Level2.png";
            }


        }
    }
```

Javascript code :

```
$(function () {
    $(document).tooltip();
});
```

I use the following css for the tool tip :

```
.ui-tooltip
        {
            text-align: center;
            max-width: 180px;
            font: bold 12px "Helvetica Neue", Sans-Serif;
        }
```

I use the references below :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

So basically the tool tip currently shows info of the title in one line something like :

```
ABC
```

I would like to display something like this in multiple lines :

```
ABC
PassPercentage = 100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery [tool tip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) doesn't allow HTML tags inside title attribute out of the box.

However, you can creates temporary place holder for each text (of repeater item). Then pass the content to tooltip when mouse hovers.

[image]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(document).tooltip({
            items: "h5",
            content: function () {
                var tooltip = $(this).siblings('.tooltip');
                return tooltip.html();
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<asp:Repeater ID="rptMonitorSummary" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptMonitorSummary_OnItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="Pnl" runat="server">
            <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
                <h5 class="ui-widget-header">
                    <%# Eval("Name").ToString().Length > 9 ? (Eval("Name").ToString()).Substring(0, 9) : Eval("Name")%>
                </h5>
                <div class="center">
                    <asp:Image Width="50px" ID="btnPerformanceImage" runat="server" Height="28px"></asp:Image>
                </div>
                <div class="tooltip" style="display: none">
                    <%# Eval("Name") %><br/>
                    PassPercentage = <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="PassPercentageLiteral" />
                </div>
            </li>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>


protected void rptMonitorSummary_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        int errorcalls = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "ErrorRatingCalls"));
        int totalcalls = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "TotalCalls"));

        float Percentage = 100 - ((((float)errorcalls / (float)totalcalls)) * 100);

        var literal = e.Item.FindControl("PassPercentageLiteral") as Literal;
        literal.Text = Percentage.ToString();
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Hey Thank you very much ! This works ! I had actually been searching online with no luck . Thank you ! I wanted to know what changes would I have to make if I want the tool tip to appear when the mouse hovers over the repeater element itself , instead of the heading ?.. but technically the question I posted has been answered. I am marking it as answered.

Comment: Hey Win The above code isnt working in IE 10 .. Would you have any solution for this ? I have a seperate question on this here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881354/jquery-tool-tip-doesnt-work-in-ie-10#18881354 .. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to use the custom content function of the jQuery UI Tooltip instead:
http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content

Using the `$(this).is("h5")` call, as in the example above, to customise the content when the user hovers over the h5 tag.