# jquery tool tip doesnt work in ie 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

The following piece of code is generating an error on IE 10 .
It works well on all other browsers .

**JavaScript**

```js
$(function () {
    var du = 1000;
    var tooltip;
    $(document).tooltip({
        show: {
            effect: 'slideDown'
        },
        hide: {
            effect: 'explode',
            pieces: 20,
            duration: du,
            delay: du / 100
        },
        track: true,
        items: "h5",
        content: function () {
            tooltip = $(this).siblings('.tooltip');
            return tooltip.html();
        }
    });
});
```

**Aspx**

```html
<div class="tooltip" style="display: none">
    <div style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
        <%# Eval( "Name") %>
        <br />
    </div>
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="font-weight: normal">Calls</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Does anyone have any solution or work around I could try ?

The error it throws is :

> JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'tooltip'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone facing the same problem 
Changing the Jquery reference to the latest version 1.10.3 resolved the problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```